# Entity/row is updated only sometimes with Spring/Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a table that gets updated (with a timestamp and a user_id) whenever someone turns "on" a device. This device table is also the "core" table that contains device_ids, device_names, etc. I have marked method with `@Transactional` from Spring, and I have the "devices" table marked as an Entity.

I would expect that when I change the entity, since the method is marked as Transactional, when the method closes, the database would be updated. But it's not (always) happening. I have checked the logs from my server, and see no SQL exceptions. catalina.out looks fine, and so does the MySQL log for errors. What could be the issue here? Should I explicitly save the updated Entity prior to the ending of this method?

Comment: `DeviceProfile` _entities_ wil be saved when you call the save method of  `DeviceProfileRepository`

Comment: @gtosto, Ok, for my curiosity then, why does the Entity get updated "sometimes", but doesn't fail all the time? (also, trying to save `Device` not the `DeviceProfile`)

Comment: Can you post your method `getDevice()` ?

Comment: maybe in another part of the application the hibernate session is flushed, or other entities _related_ to `device` are saved

Comment: @CrazySabbath updated with the getDevice() method

Comment: @gtosto , that's definitely a possibility, but since the method is marked as `@Transactional`, doesn't that get some "benefits" of a transaction, in that a new hibernate session (if necessary) is made?

Comment: yes, informally speaking, transasction will _begin_ when your method gets called,  then committed when the method `startDevice` exits. but that's all, sql statements will be executed on the db only when hibernate session is flushed/closed.

Comment: So, if I do add that DeviceProfileRepository.save(device), it should force the session to flush?

Comment: Many things happen under the hood, and they can be pretty different, depending on spring/hibernate configuration, execution environment etc ... 
I'd say if you want the entity to be saved on the then call the save method, don't rely on just transactions. They provide ACID features, but it's up to you if entity have to be saved or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, so this ended up being a race condition issue with two threads. Since one thread would start a transaction in Spring with the `@Transactional` annotation, and then another one would start, they both had the same data at one point, but one *usually* committed later, giving the impression of an issue with the row locking up. There's a reasonable solution somewhere, whether it be forcing your transactions to be of a different isolation level, for example: `Serializable` for methods touching the same row, or only updating the entity using something like `@DynamicUpdate`, but they both have pros/cons and both should be considered when trying to fix some weird race condition like what I encountered.